# Если "и конечно же" расположилось внутри предложения, как быть с обособлением вводного?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

> Известны братья инкрустациями утвари, алтарями и, конечно же, своими
>   великолепными полихромными полами.

Comment: Все верно, "конечно же" выделяется запятыми, это вводная конструкция.

Comment: Возможно, Вы не знаете, что ***и конечно же*** в начале предложения отменяет запятую после союза ***и***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Известны братья инкрустациями утвари, алтарями и, **конечно же,** своими великолепными полихромными полами.

Вводное слово ***конечно же.***

Пример: Сколько у меня всего осталось ... бессмертных вязаных вещей: сумочек, салфеток, перчаток и воротничков… **и, конечно же,** тряпичных кукол...[Дина Рубина. Медная шкатулка (сборник) (2015)]